# How to add set as wallpaper option in following code in Android

Tags: android, arrays, swipe, wallpaper

I am creating swipe action in my android app. Its working perfectly. Now I want to create set as wallpaper option so that user can set current image as wallpaper. I add some code. But its not working. Please someone help me to make current image as wallpaper.

Code-

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

    int position;
    LinearLayout full;
    Button btn;

    public Integer[] mThumbId = {
                R.drawable.kri1, R.drawable.kri2,
                R.drawable.kri3, R.drawable.kri4,
                R.drawable.kri5, R.drawable.kri6,
                R.drawable.kri7, R.drawable.kri8,
                R.drawable.kri9
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");        
        full = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.full);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        changeBackground();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(mThumbId[position]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }});
        ActivitySwipeDetector activitySwipeDetector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this);
        full.setOnTouchListener(activitySwipeDetector);
    }

    private void changeBackground(){
        full.setBackgroundResource(mThumbId[position]);
   }

    public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

        static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
        static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
        private float downX, upX;
        Activity activity;

        public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void onRightToLeftSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
            if(position < mThumbId.length - 1){
                position++;
                 changeBackground();
            }
    }

        public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
            if(position > 0){
                position--;
                changeBackground();
           }
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    downX = event.getX();
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    upX = event.getX();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                        // left or right
                        if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(); return true; }
                        if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            return false; // We don't consume the event
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'r wrong. You need to set Image bitmap for wallpaper.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA You can use `WallpaperManager.setBitmap`, `WallpaperManager.setResource`, or `WallpaperManager.setStream`.

Comment: @adneal I know that i have used that one in my app but seems to be same didn't work and after set as a bitmap it was working. so i have suggested him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare the set wallpaper permission in your AndroidManifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Comment: its working but need your little more help when I set image its too big on device screen how to fit this?

Comment: You could create a scaled `Bitmap` based on the `Drawable` of your resource ID, then call `WallpaperManager.setBitmap` instead.

Comment: If I do this its show error and say to change type of array to bitmap.

Comment: can you help me on more issue please.